# why am I getting 'GET/ 304 --' in my code? (vue.js, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

When I request data on client(vue.js) with axios,
I got a error code in server side, 'GET/ 304 --'

But I don't know why this happened
and how to approach this problem or how to fix that.

If I delete codes about 'axios' on client side,
That error doesn't show up.
Please can someone help me.

the code below:

**Client side**

```
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/")
      .then(
        result => (
          (this.greeting = result.data.greeting),
          (this.greeting2 = result.data.greeting2)
        )
      );
  }
```

**Server side**

```
export const getHome = async (req, res) => {
  let user;
  if (req.headers.authorization !== undefined) {
    try {
      user = auth.verify(req.headers.authorization);
      user = await models.User.findOne({
        where: { id: user.id }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    user = null;
  }
  const name = user ? user.name : 'Please LOGIN';
  res.json({ greeting: `Welcome to Chat N Chill`, greeting2: name });
};
```

**auth.verify code on server side**

```
  verify(token) {
    return jwt.verify(token.replace(/^Bearer\s/, ''), SECRET_KEY);
  }
```

Comment: `304` is not an error code, it just indicates that the content hasn't changed. From the client's perspective it should be just as good as a `200`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express will automatically set the status code to `304` for requests that are `fresh`:

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/response.js#L206

The property `fresh` is defined here:

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/request.js#L467

It is documented here:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.fresh

It should be nothing to worry about, it just means that the content of the response hasn't changed relative to what the browser already has in its cache.

Comment: Thanks for your comment !!
Someone let me know that should fix it.
But I have one more question.
When I open the chrome development tool, the code doesn't show up.
That show up '200' code.
Why did this happen?

Comment: @Jun You should see a `304` code in the Network section of your development tools. However, if you log the status code to the console you will see `200`. A `304` means 'used the cached copy'. The browser will use that cached copy as the response to the new request and present it with a status code of `200` so that you don't have to handle it specially in your code.

Comment: Understood 
This is my first question on Stackoverflow.
And your answer is very clear and thoughtful.
Thank you once again for your time.